# Jquery image uploader and resizer

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was wondering if it is possible to do the following:

Upload an image
Resize the image to a fixed width
Save the fixed width image and discard the original

I will be doing a lot of image uploading on my site and I am trying to move the resizing operation to the client size to reduce load on the server.

All the options I look at seem to use Jquery as only the front end, and the resizing is actually still done server side with php.

Comment: Check this: http://code.google.com/p/resize-crop/

Comment: I only want the small size one saved on my server though, this one stores the big one and just displays it smaller :(